# how to htaccess Redirect all category posts to a page

Tags: .htaccess, hebrew

I have a site with URLs in Hebrew, In which I want to redirect all category posts from a specific cat, to a specific page.

I've tried using this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 /נקודה-למחשבה/?$ http://www.zviagranot.co.il/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99/%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%94/
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work.
any idea ?

Comment: So where should `/נקודה-למחשבה/` be redirected to?

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because your file is not saved as UTF8 encoding. Make sure your editor does that.